# list swap two elements failed when using the value as index again to avoid a local variable

Tags: python, list, swap

```
l1=[0,2,1]
index=1
from ipdb import set_trace; set_trace()
l1[index], l1[l1[index]] = l1[l1[index]], l1[index]
print(l1)
```

why will `l1` be the same? `l1[1]` and `l1[2]` will not swap.

Comment: Not a proper answer, but may I kindly suggest that your code would be much more readable with an intermediate variable ?

Answer (score 3):

You can change the order, and it would work:

```
l1=[0,2,1]
index=1
l1[l1[index]], l1[index] = l1[index], l1[l1[index]]
print(l1)
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2]
```

So let's first look at the disassembly of your code:

```
import dis
def switch():
    l1=[0,2,1]
    index=1
    l1[index], l1[l1[index]] = l1[l1[index]], l1[index]
    return l1
dis.dis(switch)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              2 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
              4 LOAD_CONST               3 (1)
              6 BUILD_LIST               3
              8 STORE_FAST               0 (l1)

  3          10 LOAD_CONST               3 (1)
             12 STORE_FAST               1 (index)

  5          14 LOAD_FAST                0 (l1)
             16 LOAD_FAST                0 (l1)
             18 LOAD_FAST                1 (index)
             20 BINARY_SUBSCR
             22 BINARY_SUBSCR
             24 LOAD_FAST                0 (l1)
             26 LOAD_FAST                1 (index)
             28 BINARY_SUBSCR
             30 ROT_TWO
             32 LOAD_FAST                0 (l1)
             34 LOAD_FAST                1 (index)
             36 STORE_SUBSCR
             38 LOAD_FAST                0 (l1)
             40 LOAD_FAST                0 (l1)
             42 LOAD_FAST                1 (index)
             44 BINARY_SUBSCR
             46 STORE_SUBSCR

  6          48 LOAD_FAST                0 (l1)
             50 RETURN_VALUE
```

In this type of assignment, right hand side of the expression is evaluated first (see [Evaluation Order](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order)). So first, instruction set `(14 - 18)` loads `l1[index]`, i.e. `1`, and pushes it to stack. Then, `24-26` loads `l1[l1[index]]`, i.e. `2` and pushes it to stack. So the stack now holds `[2,1]`. [`ROT_TWO`(30)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-ROT_TWO) swaps the stack and makes it `[1, 2]`, the order we desire.

Now, in 32 - 36, the top of the stack, i.e. `1` is assigned to `l1[index]`, so now, `l1[index] == 1`, i.e. `l1[1] = 1`.

Then 38 - 42, the remaining element in stack, i.e. `2` is popped to `l1[l1[index]]`,  but now the value of `l1[index]` is 1, so you are essentially doing, `l1[1] = 1`. So let's see:

```
l1[index], l1[l1[index]] = l1[l1[index]], l1[index]

loaded == 2, 1
after stack swapping == 1, 2

l1[1] == 1
l1[1] == 2
 # So you have modified only index 1, and then overwritten it with its original value.
```

Something like this:

```
             14 LOAD_FAST                0 (l1)           ¯¯|
             16 LOAD_FAST                0 (l1)   ¯¯|  2    | 1 ---------->
             18 LOAD_FAST                1 (index)__|     __|              ↓
             20 BINARY_SUBSCR                                              |
             22 BINARY_SUBSCR                                              |
             24 LOAD_FAST                0 (l1)   ¯¯|  2 ------------------------>
             26 LOAD_FAST                1 (index)__|                      |       ↓
             28 BINARY_SUBSCR                                              |       |
             30 ROT_TWO                                                    |       |
             32 LOAD_FAST                0 (l1)   ¯¯|                      ↓       |
             34 LOAD_FAST                1 (index)__|  l1[1] = 1  <--------        |
             36 STORE_SUBSCR                                   |                   |
             38 LOAD_FAST                0 (l1)                |  ¯¯|              |
             40 LOAD_FAST                0 (l1)   ¯¯|          ↓    |              |
             42 LOAD_FAST                1 (index)__| l1[1] == 1  __| l1[1] = 2 <---
             44 BINARY_SUBSCR
             46 STORE_SUBSCR
```

If we follow the same reasoning in my solution:

```
l1[l1[index]], l1[index] = l1[index], l1[l1[index]]

loaded = 1, 2
after stack swapping == 2, 1

l1[2] = 2
l1[1] = 1
# Here, as you have not changed the value of `l1[index]` in the first assignment, the order remains.
```

Now you can follow the same logic for `l1 = [0, 1, 2]`. Though it does not need explanation, becuase both `l1[index]` and `l1[l1[index]]` are same:

```
l1 = [0, 1, 2]

l1[index], l1[l1[index]] = l1[l1[index]], l1[index]

loaded = 1, 1
after stack swapping == 1, 1

l1[1] == 1
l1[1] == 1
------------------------------------------------------------------
l1[l1[index]], l1[index] = l1[index], l1[l1[index]]

loaded = 1, 1
after stack swapping == 1, 1

l1[1] = 1
l1[1] = 1
# Here both have same value, so it does not modify.
```

So, when you are accessing indices by passing a list element as index, it is better to avoid this kind of assignment. Instead, be [***Explicit***](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):

```
l1 = [0, 2, 1]
index1 = 1
index2 = l1[index1]
l1[index1], l1[index2] = l1[index2], l1[index1]
print(l1)
# [0, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Can you explain the reason ?

Comment: @Mukesh added, please check.

Comment: @Joe it isn't supposed to either right? `l1[index] == l1[1]` and `l1[l1[index]] == l1[l1[1]] == l1[1]`