# Swapping values in a list by index

Tags: python, arrays, swap

I came across an issue swapping values in a list by using the indices as placeholders to keep track of which positive integers appeared.

The question is here (from [Leetcode](https://leetcode.com/))

> Given an unsorted integer array nums, find the smallest missing positive integer.
>
> You must implement an algorithm that runs in O(n) time
> and uses constant extra space.
>
> Input: nums = [3,4,-1,1]
> Output: 2
> Example 3

My initial approach was:

```
for i in range(len(arr)):
    while arr[i] > 0 and len(arr) > arr[i] and i != arr[i]-1 and arr[i] != arr[arr[i]-1]:
        print('swapping to index ' +  str(i) + ' value ' + str(arr[arr[i] - 1]))
        print('swapping to index ' + str(arr[i]-1) + ' value ' + str(arr[i]))
        arr[i], arr[arr[i] - 1] = arr[arr[i] - 1], arr[i]
        print(arr)
```

But this outputs:

```
swapping to index 0 value -1
swapping to index 2 value 3
[-1, 4, 3, 1]
swapping to index 3 value -1
swapping to index 0 value 1
**[-1, 4, 1, -1]** (??)
```

Whereas if I set a variable `j = arr[i] - 1` and run the same code

```
for i in range(len(arr)):
    while arr[i] > 0 and len(arr) > arr[i] and i != arr[i]-1 and arr[i] != arr[arr[i]-1]:
        j = arr[i] - 1
        print('swapping to index ' +  str(i) + ' value ' + str(arr[j]))
        print('swapping to index ' + str(j) + ' value ' + str(arr[i]))
        arr[i], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i]
        print(arr)
```

This swaps correctly

```
swapping to index 0 value -1
swapping to index 2 value 3
[-1, 4, 3, 1]
swapping to index 3 value -1
swapping to index 0 value 1
[1, 4, 3, -1] (as intended)
```

Could someone explain this to me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [list swap two elements failed when using the value as index again to avoid a local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59729342/list-swap-two-elements-failed-when-using-the-value-as-index-again-to-avoid-a-loc)

Comment: I don't understand your code - it seems you compare index with value on list - `i != arr[i]-1` - and you use value from list as index - `arr[arr[i]-1]` - but all this seems wrong. Maybe better use `print()` to see what you have in variables - `i`, `arr[i]`, `len(arr)`, `arr[i]-1`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

When you swap values

```
arr[i], arr[arr[i] - 1] = arr[arr[i] - 1], arr[i]
```

then it runs something like

```
variable = arr[arr[i] - 1], arr[i]
arr[i], arr[arr[i] - 1] = variable
```

but in second line it still has to assign values `one by one` and first it will assign

```
arr[i] = ...
```

and later

```
arr[arr[i] - 1] = ...
```

but when it assign second value then `arr[i]` will already have new value instead of old value - and this makes problem.

When you use `j = arr[i] - 1` and

```
arr[j] = ...
```

then `j` has all time the old value - ant then it works correctly.